# Prove that $3(p^2)+61$ is a perfect square only for $p = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

It is too be proved that $3(p^2)+61$ is a perfect square only for $$p=1 ; p=N$$
The question arises from a problem in arithmatic progression with a certain soft constraint of natural numbers. At the end a quadratic is formed and since our constraint is of natural number The discriminants should be a perfect square. 
If we take $p= 1$ we are able to solve the question. Our teacher left it to us to prove $p=1$ is the only solution.
I have not proceeded due to lack of ideas.

Comment: I assume $p$ is any natural number (not necessarily a prime)?

Comment: Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: I don't have a computer and find it quite difficult to do mathjax on my old Microsoft phone. I know its a hinderance but I am really sorry

Comment: Note:  $3(10^2)+61=19^2$ and $3(39^2)+61=68^2$, for example

Comment: P is any natural number

Comment: and $3(6^2)+61=13^2$ and $3(25^2)+61=44^2$

Comment: This is a [Pell-like equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html)

Comment: J.w.Tanner thanks. These will be enough to torment my teacher

Comment: Let us know your teacher's response!  When you typed p=N, did you mean p \in N?

Answer (score 4):

$q^2-3p^2=61$ is a [Pell-like equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html).

(The classic Pell equation would have $1$ instead of $61.$)

I believe there are *infinitely many* solutions to it.

Here are some:  $p=1, 6, 10, 25, $ and $39.$

---

Addendum (as suggested by [trancelocation](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/467003/trancelocation) in a comment to  [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy)'s answer):

$(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1$ so $q^2-3p^2=61\implies(q+\sqrt3p)(q-\sqrt3p)=61\implies$

$ (q+\sqrt3p)(2+\sqrt3)(q-\sqrt3p)(2-\sqrt3)=61$

$=[(2q+3p)+\sqrt3(q+2p)][(2q+3p)-\sqrt3(q+2p)],$

which means $(2q+3p)^2-3(q+2p)^2=61$,

so for any solution $(p,q)$ to $q^2-3p^2=61$ [including for example ($p,q)=(1,8)],$

there is a solution with larger integers $(2q+3p, q+2p)$.

Comment: yes. Any indefinite binary quadratic form, discriminant not a square, possesses an automorphism group, which carries any solution to  an infinite string of them.

Answer (score 2):

Given any solution with positive integers $q^2 - 3 p^2 = 61,$ we get an infinite string of (larger) positive solutions by
$$ (q,p) \mapsto (2q+3p, \; q+2p)  $$

For example,
$$ (8,1) \mapsto (19, \; 10)  \mapsto (68, \; 39) \; ...  $$

$$ (13,6) \mapsto (44, \; 25)  \mapsto (163, \; 94) \; ...  $$

By Cayley-Hamilton or direct calculation, these can be split into four one-variable recurrences, under the rule 
$$  x_{n+2} = 4 x_{n+1} - x_n  \; .$$

$$ 8, 19, 68, 253, 944, 3523, 13148, 49069, 183128, 683443, 2550644,... $$
$$ 1, 10, 39, 146, 545, 2034, 7591,  28330, 105729, 394586, 1472615, ...  $$
$$ 13, 44, 163, 608, 2269, 8468, 31603, 117944, 440173, 1642748, 6130819, ...  $$
$$  6, 25, 94, 351, 1310, 4889, 18246, 68095, 254134, 948441, 3539630,...  $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    2   3
    1   2
  Automorphism backwards:  
    2   -3
    -1   2

  2^2 - 3 1^2 = 1

 w^2 - 3 v^2 = 61 =  61

Wed Sep  4 18:54:19 PDT 2019

w:  8  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  13  v:  6  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  8 ,  -1
w:  19  v:  10
w:  44  v:  25
w:  68  v:  39
w:  163  v:  94
w:  253  v:  146
w:  608  v:  351
w:  944  v:  545
w:  2269  v:  1310
w:  3523  v:  2034
w:  8468  v:  4889
w:  13148  v:  7591
w:  31603  v:  18246
w:  49069  v:  28330
w:  117944  v:  68095
w:  183128  v:  105729
w:  440173  v:  254134
w:  683443  v:  394586
w:  1642748  v:  948441
w:  2550644  v:  1472615
w:  6130819  v:  3539630
w:  9519133  v:  5495874
w:  22880528  v:  13210079
w:  35525888  v:  20510881
w:  85391293  v:  49300686

Wed Sep  4 18:56:21 PDT 2019

 w^2 - 3 v^2 = 61 =  61

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

Comment: How did you find $(q,p) \mapsto (2q+3p, \; q+2p)$?

Comment: @trancelocation:  $(2+\sqrt3)(2-\sqrt3)=1$, so if $(q+\sqrt3p)(q-\sqrt3p)=61$ then also $(q+\sqrt3p)(2+\sqrt3)(q-\sqrt3p)(2-\sqrt3)=((2q+3p)+(q+2p)\sqrt3)((2q+3p)-(q+2p)\sqrt3)=1$

Comment: @trancelocation:  P.S.  the last number in my previous comment should have been $61$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Thanks a lot for this clarification. You should add this to your answer.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I added the one-variable Fibonacci type recurrences